# Getting Process list using WMI from a system using >90% CPU usage

Tags: powershell, wmi, wmic

We are working on a remote management software using WMI. I have a problem in getting process list from a remote device which is running with >90% CPU usage. Most of the time my WMIC command gets timed out.
 I am querying Win32_Process remotely 
Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

In PowerShell,

```
Get-WMIObject -Query "Select * From Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process WHERE PercentProcessorTime>=90"
```

Does that help?